# Delete row in database with id included in array in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an array:

```
"recipients"=>"1719122,1714979"
```

Each number in the array defines an `id`.

I have a database which includes many parameters, one of them is `id`.
All I want is: if an id in array is included in database, I want to remove it using destroy.

I tried this function:

```
@exist_recipient.each do |s|      
    s.destroy  unless @recipient.split(',').map(&:to_i).include? s.id    
    logger.info "deleted!"
end
```

`@exist_recipient` is a query which has all rows with specific condition.

This function does not work because it removes all rows: included and not included!

Any idea?

Comment: use if instead of unless ? It will remove id if its included inside of array. Or if you are using rails you can use https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/delete_all

Comment: in my case how i can use it?

Comment: `@exist_recipient.where(id: @recipient.split(',').map(&:to_i)).delete_all`

Comment: i use old version of ruby, i can use :id => instead of id : ?

Comment: tri it and you will see ;)

Comment: How old is your ruby?? The `id:` syntax was introduced in ruby 1.9, which was released in 2007!

Comment: Incidentally, `"recipients"=>"1719122,1714979"` is not an array, it's a key-value pair. `"1719122,1714979"` isn't an array either, it's a comma-separated string. `[1719122,1714979]` is an array (of integers).

Comment: ot work i receive this error: /srv/*************************************:444: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting kEND
...ipient.split(',').map(&:to_i)).delete_all
                              ^):

Comment: if i use (:id => ) i receive this error : [FedenaRescue] No method error undefined method `where' for #<Array:0x7f9ec6e6b8a8>

Answer (score 0):

In Rails you can easly use something like this code with https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/destroy_all method

```
data = {"recipients"=>"1719122,1714979"}

@recipients = data['recipients'].split(',').map(&:to_i)
# => [1719122, 1714979]
# Load DATA from specific table or use specific SQL
@exist_recipient = Table.where()
# => ActiveRecord::Relation

# Remove all data with specific ID and previously set SQL
@exist_recipient.where(id: @recipients).destroy_all
```

If you use Ruby and you need to call `destroy` method on all elements inside array

```
data = { "recipients" => "1719122,1714979" }
@recipients = data['recipients'].split(',').map(&:to_i)
# => [1719122, 1714979]
# You have this, i dont know what this is.
@exist_recipient

@exist_recipient.each { |object| object.destroy if @recipients.include?(object.id) }
```

Comment: That should probably be `destroy_all`

Comment: @Stefan changed

Comment: i your answer we suppose we have an object fix, but in my case we have some id not fix maybe 1 2 3 100000

Comment: You don't need to convert the ids to `int`.

Comment: not int i mean number of id

Comment: @tinoalberto I was commenting on the code; not your question.

Comment: @CassandraS. I prefer to use method specific types. So in this case id shoult be Integer so i convert the string i get from split to integer type

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
ModelName.where(id: @recipient.split(',')).destroy_all
```

Note: the `where` method also accepts arrays and there is no need to translate the array of stringified ids to integers with `map(&:to_i)`.